# How to use Intl.js as es2015 modules in rollup.js build

Tags: angular, module, bundling-and-minification, rollupjs

My `Angular 2` app coded in `typescript 2` uses [the Intl.js polyfill](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/blob/master/README.md).

I have set `module:"es2015"` in `tsconfig.json` to allow for tree-shaking using Rollup.js as [recommended by Angular](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#tree-shaking). in my component I just do `import 'intl'`

When I run the app in the browser, I get the error

> global is not defined

I have tried using `rollup-plugin-commonjs` to convert the library to `es2015`

**rollup.config.js**

```
plugins: [
        nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
        commonjs({
            include: 'node_modules/intl/**/*',
        })
]
```

When I run the app in the browser, I get the error:

> IntlPolyfill is not defined

On line:

> IntlPolyfill.__addLocaleData({locale:"en-US",...});

[I noticed here](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/blob/68514268e4f6b97a9323f6be9e75bd5a1216777a/CONTRIBUTING.md#source-code) that the library is written in `es6` so it should be compatible with `rollup`.  Any tips on how to use this library as `es6` modules?

Answer (score 2):

To use Intl.js as an ES6 module, you'd either need to

1. convince the maintainers to publish an ES module version alongside the other files in the [dist](https://unpkg.com/intl@1.2.5/dist/) folder (e.g. `Intl.esm.js` and so on), using the `module` and `jsnext:main` fields in `package.json` – they're already using Rollup to generate their UMD build so this would be a trivial addition, or
2. build it yourself, using the files in `src`, taking care to use the same Babel config etc.

But you *can* use it in its current form using rollup-plugin-commonjs. It turns out you just need to make sure you're importing the `dist/Intl.js` file rather than the `index.js` file (probably due to some tricky cyclical dependencies, which work differently in CommonJS to how they work in ES modules):

```js
import 'intl/dist/Intl.js';
console.log(Intl); // works!
```

This will yield better results than importing `index.js` would have even if it worked, since the dist file is generated directly from the ES modules (without the bloaty CommonJS conversion).

Comment: One wrinkle is that I only use the `en-us` locale, so I edited `intl/index.js` and changed line 6 from [this](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/blob/master/index.js#L6) to [this](http://pastebin.com/GfYSL7t2). This allowed me to greatly reduce the bundle size. Can your solution be adapted to keep this benefit you think?

Comment: One approach could be to use [rollup-plugin-replace](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-replace) to replace `locale-data/complete.js` with `locale-data/jsonp/es-US.js`